# Can't get video to fill in QGraphicsView in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface, video, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to get a video to fill a QGraphicsView. While I do get playback it only fills a portion of the view like so: [image]

Here is the code to play the video in the graphics view:

```
QMediaPlayer* player;

player = new QMediaPlayer(this);

QGraphicsVideoItem *item = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
player->setVideoOutput(item);

ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene());
ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item);
ui->graphicsView->show();

player->setMedia(QUrl("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos- 
bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"));

player->play();
```

What I would like is for the video to fill the whole window. The graphics view itself fills the window. I have tried resizing the video with `ui->graphicsView->fitinView(item)` as well as changing some scene parameters but I have not seen any difference.

Comment: what qt version are you using? 6?

Comment: Correct. 6.1 to be exact.